Is there a way to linkto pages in other sections in OneNote using the double square brackets or similar text only input?
In OneNote you can link to other pages in the section with [[page title]] but i can't find a way to refer to pages in other sections.  I'd like to do something like [[sectionName/page title]] but that doesn't work. I know I can right click and copy links but I'd plan on adding a lot of cross references and that would be cumbersome.

The square bracket links only work for pages in the same Notebook (not just the same Section).
The only supported way to link to anything (paragraph or page) in another Notebook is to copy the link.

OMG.  i thought i tested it and it didn't work between sections but i must have mistyped the page name.

Yea, people on various threads I looked through yesterday were suggesting a feature request to MS to add a Page-Title Autocomplete function that would mitigate the page title mistyping.
